# Does Resharper not support Microsoft best practices for namespace naming conventions?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper, namespaces

I know there are only warnings but they are still annoying me. I like a clean project. I have a solution with two projects. I would like for the namespaces to look like the following

Solution.Project.FEATURE

Which I thought should map onto the best practice

CompanyName.TechnologyName.FEATURE

Instead Resharper keeps suggesting a namespace of just FEATURE. I know that I can turn it off but how should I be doing this? Or am I misunderstanding Visual Studio and namespaces. Sorry I come from a Java and eclipse background where I can select a folder and click "Set as Source". Then all the packages (or namespaces) of relative to that path and it is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. I am leaving this here in case anyone else has this same sort of problem. You need to right click on the project and there you can change the base namespace name. Everything is named relative to that.